# update field by using Triggers in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

i have simple question regarding Triggers in sql.

I am completely new and i do not know how to handle it.

I have one table myshift with shiftid, starttime stoptime and lastupdate.

```
create trigger ShiftTriggerr on myshift for update as 
if update(stoptime)
update myshift set lastupdated = getdate()
```

what i want is when stoptime will update, the lastupdate field will update with getdate().

but when i run this it does not update one row but updated all rows. I do not know how to apply check on this trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `INSERTED` virtual table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.ShiftTriggerr 
ON dbo.myshift AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     IF UPDATE(stoptime)
     BEGIN
         UPDATE A
         SET lastupdated = getdate() 
         FROM dbo.myshift A
         INNER JOIN INSERTED B
             ON A.shiftid = B.shiftid
     END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

myshift ***should*** have a primary key defined, if that is `shiftId`, then,

```
  create trigger ShiftTriggerr on myshift for update as        
     update m
        set lastupdated = getdate() 
     From myshift m Join inserted i 
        on i.shiftId = m.shiftId
```